# Confusion related to permutohedral lattice

Tags: geometry

I was referring to this [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/permutohedral/permutohedral_techreport.pdf&ei=XFVGUOmqGoTy0gGVjYCwDw&usg=AFQjCNGBdVr27F8eROwdrfiSrskQWULtJg&sig2=ozsqh2j5SXHjqGgtIe0Fpg) related to permutohedral lattice.

It states that the permutohedral lattice

$$
A_{d^*}= \bigcup_{k=0}^{d}\{\vec{x}\in H_d\ |\ \vec{x}\text{ is a remainder-$k$ point}\}
$$

Where we call $\vec{x} \in H_d$ a remainder-$k$ point for some $k \in \{0, \dots , d\}$ iff all coordinates are congruent to $k$ modulo $d+1$.

I didn't get what this remainder-$k$ point means or being congruent to $k$ module $d+1$ means. I am just a beginner. I didn't get how the permutohedral lattice equation came to be like that in the end. Any suggestions?

Comment: Although the linked article refers to Gaussian filtering of data, both the article and the question appear to me to be more suitable for the mathematics site. I might be wrong but I see a lot of mathematics here but I don't see statistical, data mining or data visualization as a major part of it.  My recommendation would be to migrate it to Math.

Answer (score 2):

Although its 5 years from when the question was asked, I hope the solution is useful.

As given in the paper, a point $x=\{x_0,x_1,...x_d\} \in R^{d+1}$ is said to be reminder-$k$ point in a given $(d+1)$ dimensional space, if and only if
$$
x_i\%(d+1) = k \quad \forall \quad  i\in \{0,1,...,d\}  
$$
This means that the remainder when you divide any coordinate $x_i$ of the point $x$ by the dimension $(d+1)$ of the space, is $k$.

For eg:-

Let $d=2$ (So, the space is $R^3$).

Let $x=\{1,1,-2\}$ ( i.e. $x_0=1,x_1=1,x_2=-2$).

Now, $x_i \% 3 = \{1,1,1\} \quad for \quad i\in \{0,1,2\}$.

Hence, it is a Remainder-1 point in $R^3$ space. Another example is $x=\{3,6,9\}$, which is a Remainder-0 point in $R^3$ space.